# How to converge n windows(of start and end indices) to the least possible no. of windows such that all indices are covered

Tags: python, list, indexing

I define a window here as a tuple which has 2 items - the start and end (respectively) indices of an object. So the tuple `(0,3)` means that the window `(0,3)` has `start_index = 0` and `end_index=3`

Sample list of 6 windows

```
[(0,1) , (0,3) , (4,9) , (5,9), (6,8) , (11,13)]
```

Desired output:

```
[(0, 3), (4, 9), (11, 13)]
```

As you can see , in the output the no. of windows have been reduced to 3 compared to 6 windows in the input -- and no index in the middle of any window is "lost".

I have given it a shot myself but am not finding the desired results as my output contains more no. of windows than desired and I have to feed that output again in my "script" to get to the final stage.. It's basically converging windows wherever possible (when overlaps btw windows happen in terms of the indices in the window)

Here's my code:

```
list_ = [(0,1) , (0,3) , (4,9) , (5,9), (6,8) , (11,13)]

#creating a copy of list_ as I need to remove items when I iterate..
list_copy = list(list_)

new_list = []

for i in list_:
    for j in list_:
        if i != j:
            if (i[0] >= j[0]) and (i[1] <= j[1]):
                
                new_list.append(j)
                
                if i in list_copy:
                    list_copy.remove(i)
                if j in list_copy:                    
                    list_copy.remove(j)

output  = list(set(new_list + list_copy))

print("list_copy:",list_copy)
print("new_list:",new_list)    
print("output:",output)
```

Results(`output` is the variable for storing my result) for my code are as below , which has the window `(5,9)` unnecessarily. It gets removed  if I rerun my piece of code for the output I have received from the 1st run.

```
list_copy: [(11, 13)]
new_list: [(0, 3), (4, 9), (4, 9), (5, 9)]
output: [(5, 9), (0, 3), (4, 9), (11, 13)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work with OP's data:

```
windows = [(0, 1), (0, 3), (4, 9), (5, 9), (0, 100), (6, 8), (11, 13)]
output = []


def merge(a, b, output):
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(output):
        if a >= x and b <= y:
            return
        if (a == x and b > y) or (a < x and b == y):
            output[i] = (a, b)
            return
    output.append((a, b))

for a, b in windows:
    merge(a, b, output)

kr = set()

for outer in output:
    for k, inner in enumerate(output):
        if outer != inner and inner[0] >= outer[0] and inner[1] <= outer[1]:
            kr.add(k)

for i in sorted(kr)[::-1]:
    output.pop(i)

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
[(0, 100)]
```

Comment: thanks for giving a try , but when I add (0,100) as an additional window in my input list , I am facing a similar issue with your function above as well. Because (0,100) encompasses all indexes , that should be the only expected output but I am getting more windows in the output.

Comment: ellaborating on above.. I have kept `window` as `[(0, 1), (0, 3), (4, 9), (5, 9), (6, 8), (11, 13),(0,100)]` and I am getting `output` as `[(0, 100), (4, 9), (11, 13)]`instead of just `[(0, 100)]`

Comment: I am thinking of a way to run your function in a way that it can run multiple times but each run's `window` is the `output` of previous run.  Tried it manually and it seems to work. Because it's a pretty fast function, I think running it 5-10x shouldn't be a problem.. I will stop running the function as soon as the `output` is returned same as `window` . Will put it out as an answer in sometime as writing code in comments is not possible I guess:( . Please let me know your thoughts on it then.

Comment: @newbie101 Not sure how this can be done without 2 passes over the data. See edited answer for something that seems to fulfil the objective

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, the goal is to reduce to minimum number of intervals by merging overlapping ones.

We can use the [union-find](https://www.thealgorists.com/Algo/UsefulDataStructures/UnionFind) algorithm to efficiently identify intervals that should be merged.

**Code**

```
# Union-Find Data Structure
# Modified https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/union-find-in-python/
class ufds:
    def __init__(self, u = None):
        self.parent_node = {}
        self.rank = {}
        self.u = u
        if u:
            self.make_set(u)

    def make_set(self, u):
        ' Initialize with each element being a singlton (i.e. only itself in union)'
        for i in u:
            self.parent_node[i] = i
            self.rank[i] = 0

    def op_find(self, k):
        ' find parent of k '
        if self.parent_node[k] != k:
            self.parent_node[k] = self.op_find(self.parent_node[k])
        return self.parent_node[k]

    def op_union(self, a, b):
        ' Union a & b '
        x = self.op_find(a)
        y = self.op_find(b)

        if x == y:
            return
        if self.rank[x] > self.rank[y]:
            self.parent_node[y] = x
        elif self.rank[x] < self.rank[y]:
            self.parent_node[x] = y
        else:
            self.parent_node[x] = y
            self.rank[y] = self.rank[y] + 1


    def get_parents(self):
        ' returns the list of parents of all elements '
        return [self.op_find(i) for i in self.u]

def overlap(needle, stack):
        '''
            Check if interval needle is overlaps with stack)
        '''
        needle_s, needle_e = needle
        stack_s, stack_e = stack

        return needle_e >= stack_s and needle_s <= stack_e
    
def merge(needle, stack):
        needle_s, needle_e = needle
        stack_s, stack_e = stack
        
        return (min(stack_s, needle_s), max(stack_e, needle_e))
    
def merge_list(lst):
    result = lst[0]
    for t in lst[1:]:
        result = merge(result, t)
    return result

def process(ranges):
    # list of indexes into ranges (i.e. 0, 1, 2, ...)
    u = list(range(len(ranges)))
    
    # Union find data structure using indexes
    data = ufds(u)
    
    # Join overlapping indexes in data structure
    for i, r_outer in enumerate(u):
        for j, r_inner in enumerate(u[i+1:], start = i+1):
            if overlap(ranges[r_outer], ranges[r_inner]):
                data.op_union(i, j)

    # Result after union of overlapping indexes
    r = data.get_parents()
    
    # Merge ranges whose indexes where joined in union-find data structure
    result = []
    for v in set(r):
        lst_ = [t for i, t in enumerate(ranges) if r[i] == v]
        result.append(merge_list(lst_))
        
    return result
```

**Tests**

```
print(process([(0,1) , (0,3)]))
# Output: [(0, 3)]

print(process([(0,1) , (0,3) , (4,9) , (5,9), (6,8) , (11,13)]))
# Output: [(0, 3), (4, 9), (11, 13)]

print(process([(0,1) , (0,3) , (4,9) , (5,9), (6,8) , (11,13), (0, 100)]))
# Output: [(0, 100)]

print(process([(0, 1), (0, 3), (4, 9), (5, 9), (5, 15), (6, 8), (11, 13)]))
# Output: [(0, 3), (4, 15)]
```

Comment: I was testing out the Approach 1. It definitely helps and is working for the `(0,100)` use cases I pointed out earlier in the comment in the other answer.... Although while testing your Approach 1 , I realized that the Output Interval/Windows need not necessarily be from the Input  Interval/Windows.  For example if my Input List is `[(0, 1), (0, 3), (4, 9), (5, 9), (5, 15), (6, 8), (11, 13)]` , currently with Approach 1 I get `[(5, 15), (4, 9), (0, 3)]` , but if you notice it should ideally be  `[(4, 15), (0, 3)]` meaning `(5, 15), (4, 9)` getting merged into `(4, 15)`

Comment: Hey @DarrylG , I have added my implementation for the above comment [as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73593899/13836950). Could you please review when you have few mins. Happy to clarify anything funny in the code. Also man , I appreciate you taking the time to write up your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing on my comment on @DarrylG's answer to help with the possible improvement to the final output.

In **@DarrylG' Approach 1**, if the original list of windows is  is  `[(0, 1), (0, 3), (4, 9), (5, 9), (5, 15), (6, 8), (11, 13)]` , the output comes as `[(5, 15), (4, 9), (0, 3)]`. As you can observe the 0th and 1st item in the output i.e. `(5, 15), (4, 9)` still have  overlaps.

We could modify this output to prevent any overlap among windows by merging `(5, 15), (4, 9)` into `(4, 15)` . Hence the final output will then be `[(4, 15), (0, 3)]`

Here's my code that merges the `(5, 15), (4, 9)` into `(4, 15)`

**Functions to run on Approach 1's Output..**

```
def get_merge_windows(list_):

    new_list_= []

    for i in list_:

        intersection_list_ = [ (i,j, bool( set(range(i[0],i[1]+1)).intersection(set(range(j[0],j[1]+1))) ) ) for j in list_]
        intersection_list_ = [item for item in intersection_list_ if (item[2] == True) and (item[0] != item[1])]

        if intersection_list_:

            #it's neccasary to add i's start index in choices otherwise results may be wrong..            
            start_index_choices = [item[1][0] for item in intersection_list_] + [i[0]]
            start = min(start_index_choices)
            
            #it's neccasary to add i's end index in choices otherwise results may be wrong..       
            end_index_choices = [item[1][1] for item in intersection_list_] + [i[1]]
            end = max(end_index_choices)

            new_list_.append((start,end))
            new_list_ = list(set(new_list_))

    if new_list_ == []:
        return list_

    return new_list_

def run_multiple_times_merge_windows(list_):
    '''
        This iterative run ensures everything is converged. For example below list does not get converged in 1 go of the get_merge_windows function
        example =  [(5, 15), (4, 9), (0, 3),(4,16) , (1,95) , (2,100)]
        get_merge_windows(example) returns [(1, 100), (0, 100)] instead of [(0,100)] and hence we require another run of get_merge_windows over the output
        we got with the first run..
    '''
    new_list_ = []

    #100 is just an arbitrary number , the iterations should stop in 3-4 loops itself..
    for i in range(100):

        
        if i>0 and (new_list_ == get_merge_windows(new_list_)):
            break

        elif i==0:
            new_list_ = get_merge_windows(list_)

        else:
            new_list_ = get_merge_windows(new_list_)

    return new_list_

def get_final_windows(list_,new_list_):
    #add combined windows with windows windows that couldn't be merged..
    
    new_list__2 = list(new_list_)

    for i in list_:

        bool_list_t = [bool( set(range(i[0],i[1]+1)).intersection(set(range(j[0],j[1]+1))) ) for j in new_list_]

        
        if any(bool_list_t) == True:
            continue

        else:
            new_list__2.append(i)

    return new_list__2
```

**Testing**

```
test_list_ = [(5, 15), (4, 9), (0, 3)]
all_merged_windows = run_multiple_times_merge_windows(test_list_)
print("all_merged_windows:",all_merged_windows)
final_windows = get_final_windows(test_list_,all_merged_windows)
print("final_windows:",final_windows)
```

**Results**

```
all_merged_windows:[(4, 15)]
final_windows: [(4, 15), (0, 3)]
```

Please note that I have had to run the `get_merge_windows` multiple times due to an edge case scenario in the example presented in the doc string of `run_multiple_times_merge_windows`. But this is not a deal breaker as I have timed it and it runs 15k times per second for that example..

Comment: Congrats on deriving your own implementation.  Anyway, performing a timing test (using timeit), this implementation is ~40x slower than the one I showed (same output).  However, that may not be important).  Timing was done using the list `[(5, 15), (4, 9), (0, 3),(4,16) , (1,95) , (2,100)]`.

Comment: @DarrylG, To be clear , this is not my implementation for the original question. What I have done is supported your approach 1 with additional functions (which run on your Approach 1 Output) to give the final form as your Approach 1 output has some scope of merging further (by replacing overlapping windows by 1 window). ...Consider my code as post processing of your Approach 1..... The first 10 lines of my answer should explain this with an example. Please can you check the first 10 lines for context :)

Comment: @DarrylG Also please note  that I have fixed a bug in my code earlier so I request you to please take my new code in case you run it :)

Comment: A bit confused.  Regarding Approach 1, are you referring to my original code or my current code?  My current code merges overlapping windows.

Comment: @DarrylG , yes I think I didn't notice you have modified your version to include merging of  overlapping windows... This is very cool man and thankyou very much for the effort! Also , I will be honest and say that I am not yet able to understand the logic behind the answer (as I am a beginner). I will spend some time understanding it , but might circle back for guidance - Hope that's ok :) Thanks again!

Comment: I thought of an alternative method that should be less ad hoc based upon [union-find](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/disjoint-set-union-union-find/) algorithm.  We apply this algorithm to our list of tuples by considering them as connected if there is an overlap.  I may try this later today.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247770/discussion-between-darrylg-and-newbie101).